# Reset TCP/IP and Winsock command or module for PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

In Windows 10, When I try to use `netsh` command to reset winsock and TCP/IP for the fixing problem, I got a note:

```
In future versions of Windows, Microsoft might remove the Netsh functionality
for TCP/IP.

Microsoft recommends that you transition to Windows PowerShell if you currently
use netsh to configure and manage TCP/IP.

Type Get-Command -Module NetTCPIP at the Windows PowerShell prompt to view
a list of commands to manage TCP/IP.

Visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=217627 for additional information
about PowerShell commands for TCP/IP.
```

After searching [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/search/index?search=powershell+winsock&scope=), I'm unable to find any command or module that can accomplish these same results, with these `netsh` commands:

```
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset
netsh interface tcp reset
netsh winsock reset
```

Is there any PowerShell commands or modules which can do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Remove-NetIPAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/remove-netipaddress?view=win10-ps):

> **The Remove-NetIPAddress cmdlet removes an IP address and its
>   configuration.** To remove a specific IP address object, use the IPv4
>   Address parameter or IPv6 Address parameter. If you do not specify an
>   IPv4 or IPv6 address, the cmdlet will remove all IP addresses that
>   match.

Example of `Remove-NetIPAddress`

```
Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.1 | Remove-NetIPAddress
```

You will need to run PowerShell from an elevated prompt for the command to work.